# Intercept Silverlight DatePicker's convert from text to DateTime

Tags: silverlight, datetime, datepicker, valueconverter, lostfocus

I want `DatePicker` to convert the following text pieces to `DateTime` (shown in international format) so my customers can write a date in `DatePicker` textbox faster so it is not just `DateTime.Parse` I will use:

```
"3" to 2009-10-03
"14" to 2009-10-14
"1403" to 2009-03-14
"140310" to 2010-03-14
"14032010" to 2010-03-14
```

I have tried different methods to do it but they do not work. I have tried to bind `DatePicker.Text`/`DatePicker.SelectedDate`/`DatePicker.DisplayDate` with a custom valueconverter. But it do not work because `DatePicker` already have processed the text before I get to the text.

I have also tried to convert in the `DatePicker` `TextBox.LostFocus` like this:

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    private DatePickerTextBox textBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.LostFocus += textBox_LostFocus;
    }

    void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox == null) return;

        DateTime result;

        // This is my method for converting my special cases, 
        // parses d, dd, mm, ddmm, ddmmyy, ddmmyyyy
        if (textBox.Text.TryParseShortcut(out result)) 
        {
            // I have also tried with 
            // this.SelectedDate/DisplayDate = result;
            textBox.Text = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
            return;
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text, out result))
        {
            // I have also tried with 
            // this.SelectedDate/DisplayDate = result;
            textBox.Text = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Binding to bind data to your DatePicker, you could use a ValueConverter.

Quick example of date converter:

```
public class CustomDateValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string dateValue = (string)value;
            switch (dateValue.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, System.Convert.ToInt32(dateValue)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                //...
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // here you should implement your logic to convert your value back.

        return value;
    }
}
```

DatePickerTextBox control in XAML:

```
<controls:DatePickerTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CustomDateValueConverter}}" />
```

DatePickerTextBox in cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyData() { Data = "3" };

        _textBox.LostFocus += (se, ea) =>
            {
                _textBox.DataContext = 
                    new MyData() { Data = _textBox.Text };
            };
}

public class MyData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have just made a class called MyData to use as data in this sample.

Comment: I do use a converter. I have tried Text="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" and tried it on DisplayDate and SelectedDate which not work because my konverter is string/DateTime. How would you do it?

Comment: Hhm, value is DateTime. And if I set Mode=TwoWay I get NotImplementedException and value is also DateTime here. I write in the DatePickers textbox. It does work if it is a TextBox.

Comment: I just can't get it to work :/ Have you tested it? thanks for helping

Comment: Works if you add the LostFocus eventhandler - I have updated my sample.

Comment: You are right. It actually does. My date picker is located in a DataGrid and it does not work there. I don't know why. But my initially question is answered. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to actually start will the full control source and customize that. The problem is that the text gets updated in the TextChanged event:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._textBox != null)
    {
        this.SetValueNoCallback(TextProperty, this._textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

So by the time you get to your lost focus code, the value has already been set. I was able to get around this using subclassing, but since TextChanged handles every change I'm not sure your parse method will work (Since as soon as you hit 1 number it will get changed to a date).

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    private TextBox textBox; 

    public override void OnApplyTemplate() 
    { 
        base.OnApplyTemplate(); 
        textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("TextBox") as TextBox; 

        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
    }

    void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        if (textBox.Text == "now")             
        {                
            // I have also tried with 
            // this.SelectedDate/DisplayDate = result;                
            textBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();                 
        }  
    }
}
```

It works for me since nothing changes until it spells the whole word, but in your case that probably won't work.

Comment: No it will not work :/ but thanks anyway. I will for all costs avoid to edit a copy of the template.

Comment: In your code above you have quote marks around them, are there really quote marks or is that incorrect? Quotes would make it work.

Comment: Yes it would (I could check when #2 is written) but it is 14032010 I would write in the datepicker.